# .toFixed() not rounding number correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across an issue yesterday that when I was using Javascript/jQuery to multiply certain numbers by 100 I got a strange number returned.

I.E 16.74 * 100 = 1673.9999999999998

After searching I have found that this is to do with a floating point value and that using the `.toFixed` the command should solve the issue.

This is my code that doesn't appear to work

```
<input type="text" name="f_prodcost" id="f_prodcost" />
<input type="text" name="h_prodcost" id="h_prodcost" disabled="disabled" />
<script>
$('#f_prodcost').change(function() {
    $('#h_prodcost').val($(this).val()*100).toFixed();
});
</script>
```

I have read other questions on Stackoverflow, but I have not been able to sold the issue, and I appreciate this is probably really simple to someone who has a clear understanding of javascript/jquery, but I am currently learning so would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Number($('#h_prodcost').val($(this).val()*100)).toFixed();

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.imgur.com/YVbQEI8.png). How exactly does it not work for you? It displays an error message in the console? It prints an incorrect value? It sets the computer on fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your brackets are wrong, try something like this...

```
$('#h_prodcost').val(($(this).val()*100).toFixed());
```

You need to call `toFixed()` before passing into `.val()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a brackets issue . You have to call `toFixed` method before you set the input value

```js
$('#f_prodcost').change(function() {
    $('#h_prodcost').val(($(this).val()*100).toFixed());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="f_prodcost" id="f_prodcost" />
<input type="text" name="h_prodcost" id="h_prodcost" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to pass parameter to `.toFixed` function

```
$('#h_prodcost').val($(this).val()*100).toFixed(2)
```

this will return you upto 2 digits after the point

on this value `1673.9999999999998`  it will return `1673.99`

You can pass `toFixed()` function any number 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Digits are optional. If no value is passed, 0 is taken as default

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Your `toFixed` is still the wrong side of the parens. Which is the actual mistake in the OP.